# Floating point numbers & guard digits

Tags: floating-point

This is from "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1378). The author is discussing the problem that's addressed by using guard digits. B is the number base.

"A relative error of B - 1 in the expression x - y occurs when x = 1.00...0 and y = .nn...n, where n = B - 1. Here y has p digits (all equal to n). The exact difference is x - y = B^-p. However, when computing the answer using only p digits, the rightmost digit of y gets shifted off..."

Why does it get shifted off?

Comment: That's part of the reason I really dislike that article: every processor since the early 90s has had guard digits (they're required by the now universal IEEE754 spec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the subtraction being discussed, *x* is 1.000…, and *y* is .nn…n (in base β), where n is β−1, and *y* has *p* digits. Note that *y* = 1−β<sup>−*p*</sup>. Observe that if we align the digits of *x* and *y*:

```
    1.00…0
    0.nn…n
```

then we have *p*+1 digits in each numeral. If we are to compute the answer using only *p* digits, rather than *p*+1, then we must remove one.

That answers the question, but, to continue a bit further with the Goldberg paper, it mentions earlier that digits shifted out are merely discarded. A normal procedure in an actual implementation would be to minimize the error by, instead of discarding, rounding the number to the nearest value representable in *p* digits. However, the paper is at this point just illustrating hypothetical alternatives for computation. Given that it just discards the last digit, then instead of the original *y* = 1−β<sup>−*p*</sup>, we are working with 1−β<sup>1−*p*</sup>.